# How to fill up the username and password fields in yahoo login page using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
package newproject;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;



public class Amazon {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


String url = ("https://in.yahoo.com/"); 

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
"F:\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(url);
driver.manage().deleteCookieNamed(url);
driver.navigate().forward();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.id("uh-signin")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("myemail@yahoo.com"); 
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.navigate().forward();
driver.findElement(By.id("login-signin")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.name("password")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("login-passwd")).sendKeys("...");
//System.out.print("You are welcome");

}   
}
```

I  am trying to enter username and password in yahoo login page i am able to enter the username but not able to enter password

Comment: insufficient details. Share what page of yahoo you are accessing.

Comment: I am trying to sign in on "https://in.yahoo.com/" using the sign-in button I am able to enter a username but when the browser clicks on password through send-keys it does not proceed further.

Comment: Is it not entering the password or unable to proceed. If it is unable to proceed it might be case if password is wrong. Or you are not clicking the sign -in button below the password

Comment: Yes this is not entering the password

Comment: Add a time delay with Thread.sleep() and see if it works.. it might be a case after clicking the Next button the password page is loading slow and it is unable to find element with the id.

Comment: Still  not entering the password after adding a time delay

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Is so, please add that to you question, including the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below solution.

**Solution**

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(12, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://in.yahoo.com/");



    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@name='agree']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='uh-signin']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("Thakur_aju2008@yahoo.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-signin")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-passwd']")).sendKeys("Pranavpooja@2017");
```

Comment: Will  it also work with other locators other than xpath

Comment: Is it working for you?  I have not tried but should work without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

To fill up the *username* and *password* fields within the **Yahoo** login page `https://in.yahoo.com/` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  - Using `cssSelector`:

    ```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    //options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
    //options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://in.yahoo.com/");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a#uh-signin"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.phone-no"))).sendKeys("Thakur_aju2008@yahoo.com");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#login-signin")).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#login-passwd"))).sendKeys("Pranavpooja@2017");
    ```
  - Using `xpath`:

    ```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    //options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
    //options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://in.yahoo.com/");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@id='uh-signin']"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='phone-no ']"))).sendKeys("Thakur_aju2008@yahoo.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-signin']")).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='login-passwd']"))).sendKeys("Pranavpooja@2017");
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: yahoo_login]